# recyclerview make constraint layout loss it's constraint

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments

I got a problem when adding recyclerview to constraintlayout and then doing android.app.FragmentTransaction.replace from fragment TestDriveFragment to fragment Experiment2Fragment my next fragment loss it's constraint, but when I'm not using recylerview everything just fine.

layout fragment_test_drive.XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <layout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            tools:openDrawer="start">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvAccount"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fabAccount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
                app:fabSize="mini"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </layout>
```

Then I put this code at fab onclick to change into fragment b :

> MaintActivity.Java

```
public void fragmentTrans(Fragment a, boolean b){
    private Fragment fragment = a;
    private android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    private android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_frame,fragment);
    String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
    if (b == true) {
        ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
        Log.d(Tag, String.valueOf(b));
    }
    ft.commit();
}
```

> TestDriveFragment.java

```
binding.fabAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        private MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
    activity.fragmentTrans(new Experiment2Fragment(), true);
    }
});
```

> Both result screenshoot:

[Result fragment_experiment2 when Recycerview Removed from fragment_test_drive:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzIDi.jpg)

[Result fragment_experiment2 when Recycerview used at fragment_test_drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QA1B7.jpg)

For now I had temporary solution by setting visibility of the recyclerview to Inivisbile. But I'm still curious as why did this happen

Comment: I think it`s better to set costraint to your xml file of item that you created rather than set constraint for recyclerview.